# How to get a human-readable (e.g. RGB) value from `\e]11;?\a`?

Tags: colors, display, ansi-term

The string `\e]11;?\a` presumably yields the current terminal's background color, but I have not found a way to use this information to get the color in a human-readable (e.g. RGB) format.

I did try (cluelessly)

```
print -P '\e]11;?\a'
```

but it produces nothing, or at least nothing visible.

BTW, I'm aware of `xtermcontrol --get-bg`, but when I run it on the terminal I'm working on, I get the error:

```
xtermcontrol: --get-bg is unsupported or disallowed by this terminal. \
See also, TROUBLESHOOTING section of xtermcontrol(1) manpage.
```

(The referred-to `TROUBLESHOOTING section` did not provide any work-around.)

BTW, I have deliberately omitted details about the terminal I'm using because I'm hoping to find a general solution, rather than one that works only for a specific terminal.

Comment: If it produces nothing it means that your terminal doesn't support this escape code. For example this is the case for gnome-terminal. You may try `\e]12;?\a` (cursor color), which is more frequently supported, to see how the output should look like (something like `12;rgb:aaaa/ffff/2222`).

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of fundamental problems with this question:

1. For this to result in a general solution, the command would have to be supported by [ANSI X3.64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), the base standard for [all modern terminals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/what-protocol-standard-is-used-by-terminals/5802#5802), but as far as I can tell, that is not an ANSI command.

   I'm uncertain because I don't have a copy of that standard, I can't find one online, and ANSI won't [sell me one](http://webstore.ansi.org/). All I can find online are bastardized "references". As I describe [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/what-protocol-standard-is-used-by-terminals/5802#5802), while X3.64 is the root standard of all common modern terminals, that observation is a bit like pointing out that dogs are descended from wolves: studying wolves to learn about dogs puts severe limitations on the scope of things you can learn.

   The best resource I've found is the [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) reference, maintained by the current `xterm` maintainer. But, this is not a normative standard, it merely describes what one common program does. Many programs are derived from the `xterm` source code, but like dogs from wolves, many have diverged significantly.

   I suspect you'd find, if you chased it down, that this command was introduced by [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) as an extension to ANSI X3.64, and your target terminal doesn't support that particular `xterm` extension, which is why `xtermcontrol` fails.
2. Even if your particular set of terminals all give a reply to this command, I don't see from the [above-referenced document](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) that you're going to get an RGB value. You may well get a color name instead.

   (This is the sort of detail we expect a normative standard to nail down, which is often overlooked in functional description documents.)

   Also, beware that even if you do get an R;G;B reply, the answer can vary. If you set your color using the older ANSI X3.64 color codes, there is no standard saying which RGB color they map to; indeed, every `xterm` family terminal program I've ever used gives a way to change the RGB colors used for the ANSI color codes. Also, you can change these values on the fly in some terminal programs, so that two program runs separated by a third-party program run might give different answers because the color scheme is now different.

There is [another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/157563/programmatic-access-to-current-xterm-background-color) in the SE network that does roughly the same thing your `print` statement does, but like your command, the other answer's `echo` command gets no response from OS X's Terminal, which claims to be an `xterm-256color` terminal. That means the solution doesn't even work for all xterm family terminals.

I've written a more robust C program which diagnoses the error if it happens, and if not, shows the return values in printable form. You might find it to be a more suitable base for extension than shell commands:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char reply[40];
size_t nr;

void timeout(int sn)
{
    if (nr > 0) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nr; ++i) {
            printf("Got char %d\n", reply[i]);
        }

        if (!sn) puts("WARNING: Buffer filled!");
    }
    else {
        puts("No reply from terminal.");
    }

    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGALRM, timeout);
    alarm(1);
    printf("\e]11;?\a");

    for (nr = 0; nr < sizeof(reply); ++nr) {
        reply[nr] = getchar();
    }

    timeout(0);   /* buffer filled before alarm() timer went off! */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ANSI was basically *bastardized* from the get-go: MS-DOS's ansi.sys  became the defacto standard in the zmodem days and that influence holds today, though `xterm` definitely makes its presence felt in much the same way in a more modern sense. if you want to know what terminals can *probably* do, you should have a look at the [termcap db](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/inf514-2010/exemplos/termcap.txt), or else look into `terminfo` and `ncurses`. you might also be interested to know that the maintainer of both `xterm` and `ncurses` has written the other answer here.

Comment: @mikeserv: I don't think you can blame MS-DOS for this. The DEC VT100 is a cut-down implementation of X3.64, so the damage started in 1978, three years before DOS arrived on the scene, and probably more years than that before ANSI.SYS arrived. (I didn't use MS-DOS until 4.01, so I don't remember when it appeared, but given that MS-DOS 1.0 didn't even have a hierarchical filesystem, I'm guessing it didn't have ANSI.SYS yet.) And yes, I know who Thomas Dickey is. :)

Comment: all very good points. i dont really blame anybody, but the bbs doors of the 80s and the [34]86 home pc proliferation of the same time definitely made their mark. ansi.sys is referenced almost as often as the official ANSI code in all the documentation ive combed through in past. probably dos borrowed from the vt100 or whatever, but, as i think, the overall standard was eventually mostly compiled into dos's implementation. by the way, [here's an answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172674/52934) on this site about the escape, but ill defer to td any day on that subject.

Comment: @mikeserv: I decided to look into it, and it appears that ANSI.SYS appeared after MS-DOS 2.0 based on [the early MS-DOS source code](http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/microsoft-ms-dos-early-source-code/) released by Microsoft a few years ago. But, MS-DOS 2.0 (1983) seems to have a predecessor to ANSI.SYS, built into the base I/O system, in `SKELIO.ASM`. The source even includes `ANSI.txt`, a description of the commands it understands. It doesn't support any `]` commands. :) I would therefore guess that ANSI.SYS was broken out in MS-DOS 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is unlikely that some alternative method (other than responses to control sequences) could be the basis of "a general solution" as requested by the OP, since the property sought is not (for example) amenable to methods using the window properties.

Next, this is an example of control sequences which are implemented in xterm but not generally available.  The developer of [`xtermcontrol`](http://thrysoee.dk/xtermcontrol/) is aware of this.  His page discusses *xterm* control sequences, comments that there are many of them (a [plethora](http://thrysoee.dk/xtermcontrol/)), and mentions that OSX [Terminal.app](http://thrysoee.dk/xtermcontrol/#osxterminalapp) supports *some* of them.

The error message reported by OP is certainly clear enough.  The unnamed program on which OP attempted to run `xtermcontrol` does not support the feature.  Likely enough, it does not support a comparable feature which could be used instead.

In practice, a majority of xterm's control sequences are not implemented in other terminals, regardless of their developer's use of "xterm" for the terminal description.  See for example the xterm FAQ *[Comparing versions, by counting controls](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compare_versions)*, and the ncurses FAQ *[Why not just use TERM set to "xterm"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic)* (noting that "derived from the `xterm` source code" can be interpreted in more than one way).

The terminals of (perhaps) more interest to OP have no useful documentation on which control sequences they implement.  So the only way to find how "general" a solution you have is to exhaustively test it.  That seems not very general.

The [top-voted Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/406172/14927) is the method used by `xtermcontrol`. (The [downvoted `xrdb` answer](https://superuser.com/a/325577/14927) will not give you the current color settings from `xterm`, only its initial values — perhaps not even that.)