# A terminal-only (No window manager) terminal emulator that supports all characters

Tags: debian, terminal, raspberry-pi, terminal-emulator

I am setting up [Satnogs monitor](https://wiki.satnogs.org/SatNOGS_Monitor), which needs a lot of unusual (unicode) symbols to show a world map with symbols. In order to get them, I was using a fork of [yaft](https://github.com/wose/yaft). On my raspberry pi, I could simply open this from a terminal, it would switch to a yaft non gui terminal, and then I could run it. However, I am setting it up on another raspberry pi and symbols are not working. Instead of trying to find the underlying issue I want to just use another terminal that works (konsole works on my main machine but that requires installing all of KDE). Are there any I can start from the command line and use without a window manager, and that support all symbols?

Comment: I'd say that this had already been asked and answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177209/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196102/5132 five years ago, were it not that the proper question is _How do I expand the fonts in yaft?_.

Comment: There are two components to make this work: a terminal emulator capable of displaying unicode and a font supporting the glyphs. All [nerdfonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/) should work. My personal choice is the [tewi](https://github.com/lucy/tewi-font) font. The yaft fork uses this font by default. So you don't have to generate it yourself. Make sure you're actually using the fork on your new RPi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually tried `satnogs-monitor` on Xubuntu, and XTerm does support all the symbols required to show a decent image. So just make sure you have `xterm` command available, and try running it like `xterm -geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT`, where `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are your screen resolution dimensions. From the window that appears, run `satnogs-monitor` as you would usually do.

Here's the command I tried when testing fully DE-less X11 session on Xubuntu 19.04 in QEMU (after having stopped the `lightdm` service):

```
startx /usr/bin/xterm -geometry 1024x768
```

Typing `satnogs-monitor -s 175` in the terminal here gives me the following result:

[image: screenshot]

You'll just have to set it up to have black background and white foreground instead of the default colors. Namely, I have put the following into `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
xterm*background: black
xterm*foreground: white
```

Now the result is

[image: white-on-black screenshot]

Comment: "terminal only" and "non gui" do imply that the questioner is somewhat averse to using X as a whole.  But maybe xe is not.

Comment: @JdeBP yeah that might be true. But in this case the question should be edited to specify the missing details. The mentioning of Konsole though implies that X-based solution is not really undesired.

Comment: I ended up just installing Kubuntu, but I'll try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you're asking for, you could run a simple window manager like `i3` then fullscreen a terminal emulator like `st` or `xterm`. This saves you installing an entire desktop environment and will be nice and light weight.

You can configure `i3` to start a terminal in full screen or use `dmenu` to launch a program.

Comment: You don't need a WM just to run XTerm in full screen size. Just run `xterm -geometry 800x600` or whatever your display resolution is. But anyway, the OP is about the choice of a terminal, not WM.