# Are there any terminal emulators with "true color" support available for Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, colors, terminal-emulator

I've seen [this](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728) gist and tried a number of options, but it seems, that the versions of those terminals in stable repository are too old and I need to compile newest from source and drag newer dependencies like GTK3+ and libvte.

Is there any terminal, that can be installed on 8.5 Jessie with reasonable amount of pain and dependencies?

Comment: How many colors can your really use in a terminal window?  I doubt there would be a futuristic approach to using more than 256 colors and most terminal emulators support more than that.

Comment: Is this question limited to X terminal emulator programs?

Comment: @JuliePelletier I agree, you don't need 16m colors at the same time, but rather 16 million to **choose** from. 256 is a pretty limited palette

Comment: @JdeBP I guess not...

Comment: Not sure about Debian, but according to my memories on Ubuntu 14.04 (which was released a year earlier than Jessie) I had no problem compiling vte 0.36 and then you don't even need to recompile gnome-terminal. As far as I recall, I didn't even have problem compiling vte 0.38 (which modifies the API) and a corresponding version of gnome-terminal. That is, I didn't need any other dependencies that weren't available in the distribution. Give it a try and let us know where (if at all) you get stuck. (Don't aim for newest vte/g-t first, start with ones that are new enough to support true colors.)

Comment: Actually https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gnome-terminal says it ships g-t 3.14 and underlying libvte-2.91 version 0.38, so it should support true colors out of the box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone! Looks like I've found one that works for me: [ROXTerm](http://roxterm.sourceforge.net/). It's in the jessie stable repository and supports true color out of the box. It also a great terminal emulator overall and it doesn't bring many deps.

I think gnome-terminal might work as well, if you don't mind gnome deps

Comment: While ROXTerm is indeed a decent terminal emulator, there are two FYIs: The version shipped by Jessie uses a slightly older version of VTE (the actual terminal emulation widget) than gnome-terminal, plus ROXTerm is officially no longer maintained: https://sourceforge.net/p/roxterm/bugs/125/. That being said, it's a reasonable choice for now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; there is mine, for starters.  ☺

I asked about X because mine is intended as a user-space replacement for the virtual terminal emulator that is built in to the operating system kernel.  It's not an X program.  Like the kernel's terminal emulator, it uses the framebuffer and the various human input devices.

So if the question is whether *any* terminal emulators exist, and X is not a consideration, then the answer is most definitely yes.  My terminal emulator supports Unicode and 24-bit colour out of the box, and a slightly older version of [George Nachman's `24-bit-color.sh` script](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/master/tests/24-bit-color.sh) displays some pretty rainbows when run on it.

I'm running it right now, installed as binaries from a Debian package, on Debian 8.  (There is no local X server on the machine.)

The Debian 8 packaged Konsole also appears to support 24-bit colour.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  "[256-colour and 24-bit True Colour support](https://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/user-vt-screenshots.html#ColourSGR)". *A quick look at user-space virtual terminals*.  Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177209/5132 - *How to use /dev/fb0 as a console from userspace, or output text to it*

Answer (score 0):

you can find an upcoming project that aims at having terminal support upto 24-bit true color...

Kindly have a look here. https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728

Answer (score 0):

The `st` terminal (mentioned at the list you found) has few dependencies and should be easy to compile from source.