# Do the output of command `tty` and the file `/dev/tty` both refer to the controlling terminal of the current bash process?

Tags: tty, pty

1. From `man tty`

   > tty - print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input

   ```
   $ tty
   /dev/pts/2
   ```
2. From APUE:

   > Historically, the name of the controlling terminal in most versions of the UNIX System has been `/dev/tty`. POSIX.1 provides a
   >   runtime
   >   function that we can call to determine the name of the controlling
   >   terminal.
   >
   > ```
   > #include <stdio.h>
   > char *ctermid(char *ptr);
   > ```

   ```
   $ ls -la /dev/tty
   crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 May 26 00:16 /dev/tty
   ```

So I was wondering if the output of command `tty` and the file `/dev/tty`  both refer to the controlling terminal of the current bash process?

If yes, why does command `tty` output a pseudoterminal slave file `/dev/pts/2`, which is different from `/dev/tty`?

Since the terminal emulator `lxterminal` and the bash shell running in it use a pseudoterminal pair, isn't the pseudoterminal slave `/dev/pts/2` the controlling terminal of the bash shell?

`/dev/tty` and `/dev/pts/2` aren't symlinks to one another, so are they different files?

Thanks.

A follow up post [what relations are between my current controlling terminal and `/dev/tty`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447197/what-relations-are-between-my-current-controlling-terminal-and-dev-tty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `tty` (1) returns the name of the terminal connected to standard input. This may be the controlling terminal or it may not be. The process may even have a controlling terminal but it is not written in stone that that terminal must be connected to standard input.

From the POSIX [manual page for `tty` (1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tty.1posix.html):

> The tty utility shall write to the standard  output  the  name  of  the terminal that is open as standard input. The name that is used shall be equivalent to the string  that  would  be  returned  by  the  `ttyname()` function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1‐2008.

Try it for yourself; run

```
< /dev/null sh -c 'tty; sleep 10; echo "Done."'
```

and press Ctrl+C after seeing the message "not a tty" written out by `tty` because standard input it not a (pseudo-)terminal.

On the other hand, `/dev/tty` is always a synonim for the controlling terminal of a process, provided that the process actually *has* a controlling terminal.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate again if you could consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447197/what-relations-are-between-my-current-controlling-terminal-and-dev-tty

Comment: @Tim: If a process has a controlling terminal, `/dev/tty` is guaranteed to be a synonym of the controlling terminal. That is, `/dev/tty` and the proper name of the controlling terminal will always refer to the same physical or virtual device.

Comment: Thanks. For different sessions with different controlling terminals, `/dev/tty` is guaranteed to be their controlling terminals. How can a file be different controlling terminals, without being a symlink or hardlink?

Comment: @Tim: I don't see the difficulty. Terminal I/O is handled by the kernel, and the kernel knows perfectly well what process called it and which is the controlling terminal of that process.

Comment: Thanks. If a process doesn't have a controlling terminal, what does `/dev/tty`mean for the process?

Comment: @Tim: If the process does not have a controlling terminal, trying to open `/dev/tty` will fail and set `errno` to `ENODEV`.

Answer (score 2):

> Do the output of command `tty` and the file `/dev/tty` both refer to the controlling terminal of the current process?

Well, no, they're not the same. [`tty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tty.1.html) outputs the name of the tty connected to it's *standard input*. That's not necessarily the same as the controlling terminal (which what [`/dev/tty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) refers to).

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/12
$ tty < /dev/pts/1
/dev/pts/1
$ tty < /dev/null
not a tty
```

Of course, usually if you have `stdin` connected to a terminal, it's the controlling terminal.

The use case for `tty` that I've seen, is to determine if a script is running interactively or not. For that use, checking `stdin` instead of the controlling terminal allows to detect situations where the `stdin` is connected to something other than a terminal, and where the user can't provide interactive input. E.g. running `maybe_interactive.sh < some_input_file` from an interactive shell.

> /dev/tty and /dev/pts/2 aren't symlinks to one another, so are they different files?

`/dev/tty` can't be a symlink since the controlling terminal is different for different processes, and symlinks are the same for every process.

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if you could also consider a related post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447197/what-relations-are-between-my-current-controlling-terminal-and-dev-tty

Comment: See `/proc/self` on Linux for an example of a symlink that is different for each process.