# For a process, what are the differences between a controlling terminal and non-controlling terminal?

Tags: terminal, process

For a process, what are the differences between a controlling terminal and  non-controlling terminal?

If a process calls `open()` on a terminal's device file, will the terminal become the controlling terminal of the process' session?

Are the following different:

- creating a connection between a process and a controlling terminal and
- creating a connection between a process and a noncontrolling terminal

Are they both done by the process calling `open()` on the controlling/noncontrolling terminal's device file?

Related [Does the master device appear just like a standard terminal to the driver program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446083/does-the-master-device-appear-just-like-a-standard-terminal-to-the-driver-progra)

Comment: Also related is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405780/5132 where back in 2017 I explained that it is actually sessions that are connected to controlling terminals.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "it is actually sessions that are connected to controlling terminals." If a session has a controlling terminal, does every process in the session has opened a file descriptor for the controlling terminal? (2) If a process has opened file descriptors for more than one terminals, how can we tell file descriptors which are for  the controlling terminals of the process' session, from those which aref or noncontrolling terminals?

Comment: This is too broad a scope in my view.  You have asked six questions in one, three of which are broad enough for individual full-length answers in their own rights.

Comment: Thanks. I am not very clear about what to separate out and what to keep here. I'd appreciate it if you could answer some relevant ones here.

Comment: @JdeBP See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649796/how-would-the-existing-processes-in-the-session-learn-about-and-acquire-the-cont and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446738/when-a-session-leader-acquires-a-controlling-terminal-how-would-the-other-exist/446740

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650251/how-can-we-tell-file-descriptrs-for-controlling-terminal-from-for-noncontrolling